# How to get audio in system and microphone streaming in Mac os X?

Tags: audio, stream, operating-system, avcapturesession, aac

Same as title, I want to get the audio streaming from system and microphone. I used to download 'AVCaptureToAudioUnitOSX' from 'developer.apple.com', it teaches me use 'AVCaptureSession' to addInput 'AVCaptureDeviceInput' object, but it just can record sound.

I want to catch audio streaming and encode to type 'aac'. How to do this?

---

### Thanks all.

Comment: I think it may should set something, but i don't know it.

Comment: If know more, i want to know how to encode to 'aac' use FFmpeg libbfaac, i can't understand more from FFmpeg documents, i had already install 'faac', and i don't know what arguments should incoming.